# What is the correct way to create a new ImageItem and attach it to a FileFieldItemList?

Tags: 8

I'm writing a custom module to pull in some images from an old D6 installation (the cck plugin is failing to connect images to the correct node). So I need to be able to create new ImageItem and add them to the field.

Can I simply create a new object like:

```
$field = $node->field_gallery;
$img = new ImageItem();
$img->setValue(array(
   "target_id" => 123,
    "alt" => "Alt text"
   "title" => "Title text" 
));

$field->set($delta, $img);
$node->save();
```

Or do I need to do something with entityManager to get it linked properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any of that. You just set the values, everything else will be taken care of for you.

```
$node->set('field_gallery', [
  'target_id' => 123,
  'alt' => 'Alt text'
  'title' => 'Title text' 
]);
```

If you want to have multiple items, use `$node->field_gallery->appendItem($values);